# Font Weight with Google Fonts Roboto, normal (400) and bold (700) work, light (300) does not

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

```
Link: https://50.62.213.246/gktest/
```

The placeholder text and input text in the search bar will not respond to font-weight: 300;
If I try font-weight: 700; the text is bold.
normal = 400, light = 300, bold = 700, etc

So my question is why does the text not appear light with font-weight: 300; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your link uses the `https` protocol.

`http` vs `https` - for a protocol agnostic reference, use `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700|Roboto:400,300,700,500,100`

Basically your link uses `https` but you're referencing the `http` version of the font. So if you use `https` - it's a secure page, and as such, it will block non secure resources (especially from 3rd party websites), such as `javascript`. Or at least may display a warning, explaining that the site is trying to load `non-secure` content.

Comment: Might want to clarify that, because of this, the resource itself (the font) is blocked.

Comment: Thank you!  Switched http//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700|Roboto:400,300,700,500,100 to //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700|Roboto:400,300,700,500,100 and it works perfectly!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. All of the font weights are normal, but only in chrome on my windows pc